# watershed of IRM images

Tags: c++, image, opencv, markers, watershed

I want to apply an algorithm of segmentation of ( watershed by markers ).  I have a problem in this code. It's applied only with one image (lena.jpg)

I want to use it with irm images but it's not working.

I think that the problem is in image RGB and gray.

---

```
    #include <opencv\highgui.h>
    #include <opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp>

    #include <cstdio>
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    static void help()
    {
        cout << "\nThis program demonstrates the famous watershed segmentation algorithm in OpenCV: watershed()\n"
            "Usage:\n"
            "./watershed [image_name -- default is ../data/fruits.jpg]\n" << endl;


        cout << "Hot keys: \n"
            "\tESC - quit the program\n"
            "\tr - restore the original image\n"
            "\tw or SPACE - run watershed segmentation algorithm\n"
            "\t\t(before running it, *roughly* mark the areas to segment on the image)\n"
            "\t  (before that, roughly outline several markers on the image)\n";
    }

    Mat markerMask, img;
    Point prevPt(-1, -1);

    static void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void*)
    {
        if (x < 0 || x >= img.cols || y < 0 || y >= img.rows)
            return;
        if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONUP || !(flags & EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON))
            prevPt = Point(-1, -1);
        else if (event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN)
            prevPt = Point(x, y);
        else if (event == EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && (flags & EVENT_FLAG_LBUTTON))
        {
            Point pt(x, y);
            if (prevPt.x < 0)
                prevPt = pt;
            line(markerMask, prevPt, pt, Scalar::all(255), 5, 8, 0);
            line(img, prevPt, pt, Scalar::all(255), 5, 8, 0);
            prevPt = pt;
            imshow("image", img);
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        char* filename = argc >= 2 ? argv[1] : (char*)"samah.png";
        Mat img0 = imread(filename, 1), imgGray;

        if (img0.empty())
        {
            cout << "Couldn'g open image " << filename << ". Usage: watershed <image_name>\n";
            //system("wait");
            return 1;
        }
        help();
        namedWindow("image", 1);

        img0.copyTo(img);
        cvtColor(img, markerMask, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        cvtColor(markerMask, imgGray, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        markerMask = Scalar::all(0);
        imshow("image", img);
        setMouseCallback("image", onMouse, 0);

        for (;;)
        {
            int c = waitKey(0);
            if ((char)c == 27)
                break;

            if ((char)c == 'r')
            {
                markerMask = Scalar::all(0);
                img0.copyTo(img);
                imshow("image", img);
            }

            if ((char)c == 'w' || (char)c == ' ')
            {
                int i, j, compCount = 0;
                vector<vector<Point> > contours;
                vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

                findContours(markerMask, contours, hierarchy, RETR_CCOMP, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

                if (contours.empty())
                    continue;
                Mat markers(markerMask.size(), CV_32S);
                markers = Scalar::all(0);
                int idx = 0;
                for (; idx >= 0; idx = hierarchy[idx][0], compCount++)
                    drawContours(markers, contours, idx, Scalar::all(compCount + 1), -1, 8, hierarchy, INT_MAX);

                if (compCount == 0)
                    continue;



    vector<Vec3b> colorTab;
            for (i = 0; i < compCount; i++)
            {
                int b = theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
                int g = theRNG().uniform(0, 255);
                int r = theRNG().uniform(0, 255);

                colorTab.push_back(Vec3b((uchar)b, (uchar)g, (uchar)r));
            }

            double t = (double)getTickCount();
            watershed(img0, markers);
            t = (double)getTickCount() - t;
            printf("execution time = %gms\n", t*1000. / getTickFrequency());

            Mat wshed(markers.size(), CV_8UC3);

            // paint the watershed image
            for (i = 0; i < markers.rows; i++)
                for (j = 0; j < markers.cols; j++)
                {
                    int index = markers.at<int>(i, j);
                    if (index == -1)
                        wshed.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
                    else if (index <= 0 || index > compCount)
                        wshed.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = Vec3b(0, 0, 0);
                    else
                        wshed.at<Vec3b>(i, j) = colorTab[index - 1];
                }

            wshed = wshed*0.5 + imgGray*0.5;
            imshow("watershed transform", wshed);
        }
    }

    system("wait");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: we are likely to need more information on what is going wrong and how you've tried to fix it in order to help you.  take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this code is correct.
the pbm is that its execute only with one picture (colored)
i need a solution that make this code execute with IRM images (gray picyure)